# Symfony is slow on production server, not in local

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, server

I have a performance problem with my symfony stack.

Because an image is worth than a long text :

[On production (AWS EC2 t2.medium)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiqZM.png) (2387ms, 84MiB)(ParamConverterListener take 2326ms and 84MiB..)

[On local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVXJd.png) (51ms, 8MiB)(No ParamConverterlistener or under 1ms)

In local I used symfony server command to run my server, no extra configuration.

On server, I activate and configure Opcache, increase realpath size and ttl and use nginx sample configuration present in symfony documentation, APCu is activate too.

For database, I use AWS RDS, with default configuration.

My doctrine.yaml :

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    types:
        enumProjectStatus: App\Enum\EnumProjectStatus
        enumFeaturedPeriodArea: App\Enum\EnumFeaturedPeriodArea
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    options:
        1002: 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""))'
    mapping_types:
        enum: string
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

If someone have any information about this *ParamConverterListener* (or *BlameConverter* when i'm login).

Thanks.

PS: I'm not an symfony and PHP expert. So if I missing something don't hesitate to tell me what.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Looks like database connectivity/optimization related issues, since [ParamConverterListener](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html#doctrine-converter) is typically used to convert the route parameters to Doctrine Entities. Please edit your question to include more debugging details regarding the database connectivity and other cache related optimizations that may differ from dev and production. ATM it would be like trying to find a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 1):

problem is resolve when I set server_version in database connection configuration.

Thanks.